# Conditionnal side effect import in typescript

Tags: typescript

I will try to be as specific as possible.

I actually have two environment files, **config_prod** and **config_dev** for production and development respectively.

```
config_dev
{
   newrelic: false
}

config_prod
{
   newrelic: true
}
```

I load one of its files from the NODE_ENV and via a condition

```
this.currentConf = require(`./config_${env}`);
```

Now I wish I could use the module newrelic by checking whether or not according to my config, I can load the module.

```
import * as someMobudle from 'someModule';

if (config.get('newrelic')) {
     require('newrelic');
}
```

Here are my questions:

1 - Is it a good practice to **mix** in typescript the **import ES6** and **require of CommonJS** in the same file?

2 - For conditional side effects as in the example above. Typescript proposed what except `import module = require('module')` (which only functions at the beginning of the file).

3 - How could I avoid Tslint errors of the type **no-var-requires**